# ¿Cómo se comparan cadenas en Bash?

Tags: linux, string, bash

Estoy utilizando Bash en Linux y encontré un ejemplo en el que comparaba las cadenas de esta forma pero al parecer no funciona.

En este caso, `$a` es lo que el usuario escribe en la consola.

```
#!/bin/bash
a=$1
if [ "${a}"=="static" ]; then
(instrucciones)
else
(instrucciones)
fi
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Puedes hacer `help test` para mas información:

Cadena vacía:

```
if [ -z "$VAR" ]; then ...
```

Cadenas iguales

```
if [ "$VAR" = "CADENA" ]; then ...
```

Cadenas distintas

```
if [ "$VAR" != "CADENA" ]; then ...
```

Comment: Mi error era que debe haber espacio entre las cadenas y el signo = .
En otros lenguajes ponerlos juntos no importa pero en este caso si.

Comment: @FrikyEquisDe Los espacios **no importan**. `if[ "$USER" = "trauma" ]; echo 'Hola, Trauma !'; fi` funciona correctamente, al menos en mi `bash 4.3.16`. ¿ Seguro que son los espacios ? Tiene que haber algo mas.

Comment: Sí,  me refiero a ponerlo de esta forma:       if[   "$VAR"="CADENA"   ]    así no funciona,  pero de la forma en que los has escrito tú sí que sirve.

Comment: Curioso. A mi me funciona en **ambas** formas, con o sin espacios, usando `/bin/bash` o `/bin/sh`, tanto dentro de un archivo como desde la línea de comandos. Donde **si** importan es en el espacio entre el `if` y el `[`.

Comment: Yo estoy usando Slackware,  y tú que distribución? Quizá sea eso.

Comment: Pues seguro, tiene que ser eso. `Ubuntu Yakkety`. Es raro: ¿ mis scripts bash no te funcionarian a tí ? Es una forma de volver loco a cualquiera. Menos mal que no escribo muchos ;-)

Comment: `if[` es incorrecto, el operador `[` debe tener espacios alrededor porque es un comando en sí mismo --> `if [`

Comment: @fedorqui cierto. Respuesta corregida.

Answer (score 7):

En Bash se pueden comparar las cadenas utilizando la sintaxis:

```
[[ $variable == "valor" ]]
```

Nótese que aquí `$variable` no necesita llevar comillas dobles.

Aquí, tanto `[[` como `==` son características propias de Bash (lo que llamamos *Bashisms*). Lo estándar (es decir, lo que define POSIX) es utilizar `[` y `=`:

```
[ "$variable" = "valor" ]
```

En cuyo caso la variable sí debe ir entrecomillada para protegernos del *word splitting*.

---

Nótese que la sintaxis es de la forma:

```bash
if [ condiciones ]
# ^ ^           ^
```

Es decir, los espacios alrededor de `[` son necesarios, pues `[` es un comando en sí mismo. Este comando se llama `test` y por tanto puedes utilizar `[` y `test` indistintamente, así como buscar sus intrucciones haciendo `man test` (tal y como indicó Trauma en su respuesta):

```
$ v="hola"
$ if test "$v" = "hola"; then echo "si"; fi
si
$ if [ "$v" = "hola" ]; then echo "si"; fi
si
```

---

#### Explicación adicional respecto el uso de comillas dobles dentro de `[` y `[[`.

Cuando utilizamos `[`, las variables se expanden provocando errores si no le ponemos comillas dobles:

```
$ v="hola que tal"
```

Con `[` y comillas, la expansión es correcta:

```
$ if [ "$v" = "hola que tal" ]; then echo "si"; fi
si
```

Si quitamos las comillas, da error:

```
$ if [ $v = "hola que tal" ]; then echo "si"; fi
bash: [: too many arguments
```

Pues se está expandiendo a:

```
$ if [ hola que tal = "hola que tal" ]; then echo "si"; fi
```

dando 5 argumentos a `test` en lugar de los máximos 3 aceptados.

En cambio, con el Bashismo `[[` sí se pueden omitir las comillas:

```
$ if [[ $v = "hola que tal" ]]; then echo "si"; fi
si
```

Comment: Mucho mejor explicado. Y desconocía `[[`.

Answer (score 2):

Ejemplos:

```
test="test"
if [[ $test == "test" ]]; then
    echo "Son iguales las cadenas."
elif [[ ! $test ]]; then
    echo "La cadena está vacía entonces."
elif [[ $test =~ "^t" ]]; then
    echo "El regex indica que la cadena ${test} empieza con t"
elif [[ ${test:1:1} == "e" ]]; then
    echo "Aquí estamos comparando el caracter 1 con la letra e, es verdadero"
fi
```

cada uno indica que hace, es fácil de entender.