# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre (( )) y [[ ]] en una sentencia if?

Tags: bash

```
Uno=1
Dos=2

 # aquí la salida es S
if (( Uno < Dos )); then echo S; else echo N; fi

 # aquí la salida es N
if [[ Uno < Dos ]]; then echo S; else echo N; fi
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(( expresión ))` permite evaluar [expresiones aritméticas](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic). Si el valor de la expresión es no-cero, el estado de retorno es 0; en caso contrario, el estado de retorno es 1.

`[[ expresión ]]` es un bashism (algo propio de Bash, mientras que `[` es genérico -- puedes leer sobre la [diferencia entre `[` y `[[`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/50048/83)) y sirve para evaluar expresiones, que pueden ser mucho más complejas que las aritméticas.

Así, cuando dices `(( uno < dos ))`, el intérprete mira el valor de `$uno` 
y `$dos` y evalúa cuál es mayor.

Sin embargo, cuando dices `[[ uno < dos ]]`, el intérprete evalúa lexicográficamente las cadenas "uno" y "dos" y determina que "uno" no es mayor que "dos".

> When used with [[, the ‘<’ and ‘>’ operators sort lexicographically using the current locale. <sub>[fuente (inglés)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs)</sub>

```
$ [[ a < b ]] && echo "sí" || echo "no"
sí
$ [[ b < a ]] && echo "sí" || echo "no"
no
```

Para evaluar el *contenido* de las variables en `[[` debes usar `$` para que su valor se expanda:

```
[[ "$b" -lt "$a ]]
```

Donde `-lt` quiere decir "lower than", es decir, *menor que*. En total son: ‘-eq’, ‘-ne’, ‘-lt’, ‘-le’, ‘-gt’ y ‘-ge’.

Por ejemplo:

```
$ a=5
$ b=10
$ [[ "$b" -lt "$a" ]] && echo "b menor que a" || echo "b MAYOR que a"
b MAYOR que a
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando utilizas los corchetes tienes que utilizar sintaxis diferente, es decir :

```
if [[ Uno -lt Dos ]]; then echo S; else echo N;
```

Con los corchetes se permiten introducir comandos de consola.

Comment: Esta respuesta está incompleta. Deberías añadir más detalles para que realmente responde a lo que se pide en la pregunta. Que es una sintaxis diferente está claro, pero cuál es la diferencia entre las dos sintaxis, cuál es la diferencia entre usar los paréntesis o los corchetes.