# ¿Por qué un if [[ ]] no me funciona en este script de Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

Estoy trabajando es rapberry pi 3B y tengo este bash con el que intento buscar el puerto de comunicaciones correspondiente a un determinado dispositivo.

```
    #!/bin/bash
   for sysdevpath in $(find /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*/ -name dev); do
 (
   syspath="${sysdevpath%/dev}"
   devname="$(udevadm info -q name -p $syspath)"
   eval "$(udevadm info -q property --export -p $syspath)"
  # if [[ "${ID_SERIAL}" == *"STM32_Virtual_ComPort"* ]] ;then
  #  if [[ "${ID_SERIAL}" =~ "STM32_Virtual_ComPort" ]] ;then
  #  if [[ "${ID_SERIAL}" == *"STM32_Virtual_ComPort"* ]] ;then
  #  if [[ "$(echo "$ID_SERIAL" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')" == *"STM32_Virtual_ComPort"* ]] ;then
    if [[ "${ID_SERIAL,,}" == *"STM32_Virtual_ComPort"* ]] ;then
   #if [ $ID_SERIAL = *'STM32_Virtual_ComPort'* ]; then
       echo "/dev/$devname - $ID_SERIAL"
   fi
)
done
```

Esta es la lista puerto->dispositivo sin filtrar:

```
/dev/bus/usb/001/001 - Linux_4.19.58-v7+_dwc_otg_hcd_DWC_OTG_Controller_3f980000.usb
/dev/hidraw1 -
/dev/input/event1 - CHICONY_Asus_Keyboard
/dev/bus/usb/001/005 - CHICONY_Asus_Keyboard
/dev/hidraw2 -
/dev/input/event2 - CHICONY_Asus_Keyboard
/dev/usb/hiddev0 -
/dev/bus/usb/001/003 - 0424_ec00
/dev/bus/usb/001/002 - 0424_9514
/dev/bus/usb/001/011 - 0424_2517
/dev/bus/usb/001/020 - STMicroelectronics_STM32_Virtual_ComPort_00000000001A
/dev/ttyACM0 - STMicroelectronics_STM32_Virtual_ComPort_00000000001A
/dev/hidraw0 -
/dev/input/mouse0 - Logitech_USB_Optical_Mouse
/dev/input/event0 - Logitech_USB_Optical_Mouse
/dev/bus/usb/001/004 - Logitech_USB_Optical_Mouse
```

El problema esta en el `if` (como se puede ver por las lineas comentadas, que son las diferentes pruebas que he hecho), que no se realiza correctamente.

Si se ejecutase correctamente deveria darme la siguiente salida:

```
/dev/bus/usb/001/020 - STMicroelectronics_STM32_Virtual_ComPort_00000000001A
/dev/ttyACM0 - STMicroelectronics_STM32_Virtual_ComPort_00000000001A
```

Comment: no acaba de quedar claro el problema. Indica cuál es la lógica que debería seguir en lugar de que tengamos que deducirla nosotros. También iría bien simplificar el ejemplo a lo que es estrictamente necesario, quitando el código que no lo es.

Comment: La pregunta sigue sin estar clara. De todos modos parece que se trata de comparar cadenas

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo se comparan cadenas en Bash?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/50041/c%c3%b3mo-se-comparan-cadenas-en-bash)

Comment: @fedorqui no, al final fue tema de sh vs bash. El código es correcto por bash, pero el OP lo usa con sh

Comment: @terdon ah vale! Edito la pregunta pues para reflejarlo. Gracias y buena respuesta!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo puedes simplificar a:

```
find /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*/ -name dev | 
    while IFS= read -r sysdevpath; do
        syspath="${sysdevpath%/dev}"; 
        devname="$(udevadm info -q name -p $syspath)"; 
        ID_SERIAL=$(udevadm info -q property --export -p $syspath | 
                    grep -oP "ID_SERIAL='[^']+"); 
        grep -q STM32_Virtual_ComPort<<<"$ID_SERIAL" && 
            echo "/dev/$devname - $ID_SERIAL"; 
    done
```

Es siempre mejor evitar el `eval` con datos que no controlas a 100% ya que no se sabe que vas a ejecutar.

Dicho eso, tus `if` deberían funcionar. Y si que funcionen:

```
$ ID_SERIAL="STMicroelectronics_STM32_Virtual_ComPort_00000000001A"
$ if [[ "${ID_SERIAL}" == *"STM32_Virtual_ComPort"* ]]; then echo si; fi
si
$ if [[ "${ID_SERIAL}" =~ "STM32_Virtual_ComPort" ]] ;then echo si; fi
si
```

Si no te funcionen a ti, será que el `eval` no esta funcionando exactamente como esperas y el valor que tienes en el `${ID_SERIAL}` no es lo que crees y nos muestres.

Pero fíjate que lo tienes que ejecutar con `bash` y no con `sh`. Si lo haces con `sh`, no funcionarán tus `if` ya que el `[[ ]]` no existe en `sh` y tampoco el `=~`.

Comment: gracias terdon, tu script simplificado tambien me da error:

      test.sh: 7: test.sh: Syntax error: redirection unexpected

La linea 7 corresponde a la linea del grep.
Sospecho que el problema esta en el sistema operativo, que al ser un debian modificado (raspbian) para raspberry no se comporta igual que otros debian. Por que si no no entiendo que funcione en un ubuntu por ejemplo y no en la raspberry.

Comment: @Quarkbite es porque lo estas corriendo con `sh` y no con `bash`. Intentalo con bash y funcionará. O bien ejecutalo con `bash script.sh` o cambia el [shebang](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang) de `#!/bin/sh` a `#!/bin/bash`. Eso también explica porque no te funcionaban los `if` ya que el `[[ ]]` no existe en `sh` sino solo en bash.

Comment: Muy buena, tenia la idea de que con esta linea  #!/bin/bash ya se estaba ejecutando en BASH, aunque luego lo lanzase con sh test.sh, Lanzandolo con bash test.sh funciona perfectamente. Muchas gracias

Comment: @Quarkbite ¡de nada! si tienes el shebang, no hace falta lanzarlo _con_ algo. Simplemente hazlo ejecutable (`chmod a+x script.sh`) y lanzalo con su nombre: `./script.sh` o `/path/to/script.sh`.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando se habla de bash existen múltiples formas de conseguir el mismo objetivo, dependiendo de las circunstancias. La razón principal por lo que la mayoría de los códigos de bash, suelen fallar cuando se "mueven de un sitio a otro" es por **falta de contexto**. Saber como se está ejecutando ese script y que "necesidades tiene", ya que esto trae ciertas ventajas o inconvenientes como compatibilidad, seguridad, formas de uso..

**Existe diferencia en ejecutar** `sh miscript.sh`, `. miscript.sh` y `./miscript.sh`, por otro lado, el uso correcto del hasbang https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365130/what-is-the-difference-between-usr-bin-env-bash-and-usr-bin-bash

**Mi respuesta falla en tu caso** por que haces uso de "sh" para ejecutar el script, esto provoca que se ejecute en un **nuevo proceso del shell**

Existen otras dos formas que dan otro comportamiento a la ejecución:

- . script.sh,(nótese un punto al comienzo) ejecuta el archivo en el proceso actual del shell.
- ./script.sh ejecutará el archivo en el directorio actual. El archivo puede ser un ejecutable binario, o puede comenzar con una línea denominada "hashbang" `#!/bin/bash` o `#!/usr/bin/env bash` y debe presentar el indicador ejecutable.

Sabiendo esto, analizaría si realmente estoy ejecutando el script de la forma adecuada y que es lo que mas me conviene según sea nuestro caso, projecto y circunstancias.

**SOLUCIÓN.**

---

Lo he comprobado simulando el data output en un data.txt y haciendo una lectura del archivo linea a linea.

```
cat ./data.txt | while read fileLine
do
   matchValue="STM32_Virtual_ComPort"
   if [[ $fileLine == *$matchValue* ]]; then
       echo "$fileLine"
   fi
done
```

por lo que dentro de tu `for`
quedaría así

```
   syspath="${sysdevpath%/dev}"
   devname="$(udevadm info -q name -p $syspath)"
   eval "$(udevadm info -q property --export -p $syspath)"
   matchValue="STM32_Virtual_ComPort"

   if [[ $ID_SERIAL == *$matchValue* ]]; then
       echo "/dev/$devname - $ID_SERIAL"
   fi
```

Saludos!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que tambien lo probe, no funciona, me devuelve lo siguiente en cada iteracion.

test.sh: 9: test.sh: [[: not found

La linea 9 corresponde al if.

Comment: No, el `=` en el `[` o el `[[` es la manera correcta y portable de comparar valores aritméticos. El `==` solo existe en el `[[` y en unos shells como bash y no todos, pero el `[ $a = $b ]` siempre es comparación y nunca declaración de valor. Mira https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html. Y si, lo se que es super raro, pero así es.

Comment: Tienes razón @terdon, sin embargo, depende del contexto, yo me he ceñído al código que el ha mostrado y PREGUNTADO en el título de la misma que es haciendo uso de  [[ ]]. Porfavor, lean el contenido adicional de la respuesta y se agradecería una valoración ecuánime

Comment: El voto negative era porque decias que `[[ $a = $b ]]` era incorrecto, ahora que quitaste esto (gracias!) lo quité. Pero temo que tu respuesta sigue siendo, no incorrecta, sino no relevante al tema en cuestión. El `sh` (bourne shell) *no* es lo mismo que `bash` (bourne-again shell). Eso es el problema aquí y no tiene nada que ver con las diferentes maneras de ejecutar. El OP hacía `sh script.sh`, entonces ejecutandolo con `sh` y no `bash`. El shebang se ignora si pasas el script como argumento de este manera. Y como el `[[`, y el `=~` no existen en `sh`, el script fallaba.

Comment: Gracias a ti, una oportunidad para aprender algo mas. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

no me gusta mucho la solucion pero he conseguido que se ejecute adecuadamente el filtro utilizando grep,de este modo.

```
    if echo "$ID_SERIAL" | grep -q "STM32_Virtual_ComPort"; then
```