# ¿Cómo comparo un argumento con una cadena en Bash?

Tags: bash, string

Tengo problemas para pasar argumentos a mi script en `bash`. Para simplificar hice este ejemplo que de la misma manera no funciona.

Se supone que al al invocarlo como `programa.sh piedra` debe darte un mensaje, si no coincide con el esperado te da un error. Pero no me funciona, siempre me dice "PAPEL":

```
#!/bin/bash
# programa.sh

if [ "$1"="papel" ]; then
        echo -e ""
        echo -e "Hola invocaste PAPEL"
        echo -e ""
elif [ "$1"="piedra" ]; then
        echo -e ""
        echo -e "Hola invocaste PIEDRA"
        echo -e ""
else
        echo -e "Error: solo se soportan los argumento: papel y piedra"
fi
```

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo se comparan cadenas en Bash?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/50041/c%c3%b3mo-se-comparan-cadenas-en-bash)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Los argumentos sí pueden ir entre comillas, de hecho así se preserva el `IFS` y se evita la separación por estos en caso de que el parámetro contenga un carácter perteneciente al `IFS` (tab, espacio, salto de línea)

Tu problema principal radica en los espacios en el evaluador `[]`

Es decir, en lugar de

```
[ "$1"="papel" ]
```

tendría que ser

```
[ "$1" = "papel" ]  # Nota los espacios entre "$1" e = y "papel"
```

Puedes usar sin problema el operador `=` porque compara cadenas dentro del evaluador `[`.

Para que Bash entienda un *token* revisa con base en los separadores (tab, espacio, salto de línea), es decir, lo que contenga la variable `IFS`. El operador `[` analizaría con base en algún token, en este caso "=", y para que se reconozca como tal debe estar separado de lo demás por espacios, sino sólo estás concatenando el argumento "$1" a la cadena "=" y a la cadena "papel"; eso siempre te evaluará como verdadero, ya que es una cadena no vacía, y siempre te dará el bloque "Hola invocaste PAPEL".

Una vez puesto los espacios, tu código debería quedar algo así.

```
#!/bin/bash
# programa.sh

if [ "$1" = "papel" ]; then
#        |_|__ Aqui van los espacios.
        echo -e ""
        echo -e "Hola invocaste PAPEL"
        echo -e ""
elif [ "$1" = "piedra" ]; then
#          |_|__ Aqui van los espacios.
        echo -e ""
        echo -e "Hola invocaste PIEDRA"
        echo -e ""
else
        echo -e "Error: solo se soportan los argumento: papel y piedra"
fi
```